# Does retraining a soldier in the AWC also reroll their perk?

Tags: xcom-2

As title. If a soldier has a bonus ability which doesn't fit (eg I got Lightning Reflexes on a sniper... I think he's never been shot at in 20 missions), can I retrain him so as to get a chance at a different bonus?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the cross class perk is determined when you first obtain the character.  Retraining will not change the skill.

Comment: This is actually useful, as you can retrain somebody's skills once you see what their cross class skill is, so that the other skills work with it better. If a sniper has lightning reflexes, maybe it would make more sense to make them use pistols and get up on the enemy.

Comment: @DCShannon on the other hand, having a squad of serial rangers would make the game even easier than it is :)

Comment: Yeah, that would be nice. The point remains, though. I got rapid shot on a grenadier and retrained a bit. Would have hated to lose that.

Comment: On the other hand, retraining *before* unlocking the cross-class perk... will re-roll the cross-class perk!

Comment: @RavenDreamer: does this mean that for a soldier who missed getting his/her AWC bonus because it was "rolled" at an early level before the AWC was built will never get a perk or does it mean that he/she will have a chance at getting one on retraining?

Comment: To answer my own uncertainty, the missed AWC perk is gone for good (i.e. can't ever be obtained on respec) since the June patch according to https://www.reddit.com/r/Xcom/comments/4vlfyd/not_getting_awc_perk_even_with_retraining/

Answer (score 0):

Related to this: while you can't change the perk (as z' noted), there is a mod that lets you choose which perk you get.

[Chooseable AWC Perks](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=625272665)

Currently it's only available on the Steam Workshop, not at Nexusmods.